# Running the tomcat server getting output as directory listings for /

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc, tomcat

Iam learning Spring MVC through certain set of examples. i have downloaded a simple example from this link  https://github.com/frenmanoj/bookstore

Configured the Project properly when running the Projects iam getting the Directory Listing Page, iam not understanding

below is the Page and Console output

http://localhost:9000/bookstore/

```
Directory Listing For /

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Filename Size Last Modified 

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Apache Tomcat/8.0.9


Mar 09, 2015 7:38:42 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_31\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_31/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_31/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_31/lib/i386;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;D:\maven\bin;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;F:\eclipse;;.
Mar 09, 2015 7:38:42 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:bookstore' did not find a matching property.
Mar 09, 2015 7:38:43 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-9000"]
Mar 09, 2015 7:38:43 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Mar 09, 2015 7:38:43 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Mar 09, 2015 7:38:43 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Mar 09, 2015 7:38:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 2007 ms
Mar 09, 2015 7:38:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Mar 09, 2015 7:38:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.9
Mar 09, 2015 7:38:44 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [132] milliseconds.
Mar 09, 2015 7:38:45 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-9000"]
Mar 09, 2015 7:38:45 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Mar 09, 2015 7:38:45 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1532 ms
```

Almost i have tried 3 to 4 examples from past 2 Days experiencing the same output in all them what is wrong with the example can anyone please help me

Comment: What happens if you hit http://localhost:9000/bookstore/book

Comment: When i hit the url  http://localhost:9000/bookstore/book  i will get the below message     HTTP Status 404 - /bookstore/book

type Status report

message /bookstore/book

description The requested resource is not available.


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Apache Tomcat/8.0.9

Answer (score 0):

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.Servlet1.MyServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>listings</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>    <!-- This setting enables/disables directory listings -->
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
```